# meteor js simpleschema Index with pattern already exists with different options

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor js w/ simple-schema and getting

`MongoError: Index with pattern: { username: 1 } already exists with different options`

My schema around the db.users collection is

```
Schema = {};

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
...
 username: { 
     type: String, 
     unique: true, 
     regEx: /^[a-z0-9]{3,32}$/ , 
     max: 32,
     min: 3 },
...
});
```

I've dropped the index in mongodb but am still getting the error when I restart my app.  Anyone come across this ?

Comment: btw why set min and max again? regEx might be ok.. and probably you want to include A-Z too (or make it case insensitive: /^[a-z0-9]{3,32}$/i

in addition.. is it a good idea to let usernames start with a number? you decide ;)

Answer (score 0):

Meteor comes with some default indexes on the `users` collections. From [accounts-base](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js):

```
/// DEFAULT INDEXES ON USERS
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('username', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('emails.address', {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('services.resume.loginTokens.hashedToken',
                          {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('services.resume.loginTokens.token',
                          {unique: 1, sparse: 1});
// For taking care of logoutOtherClients calls that crashed before the tokens
// were deleted.
Meteor.users._ensureIndex('services.resume.haveLoginTokensToDelete',
                          { sparse: 1 });
// For expiring login tokens
Meteor.users._ensureIndex("services.resume.loginTokens.when", { sparse: 1 });
```

I have not checked but I'm guessing `unique: true` may be the part of your schema that is conflicting with the above.

Answer (score 0):

you can perfectly merge your schema with the existing one where index and unique is already set for username and email. as you only remove them by setting them explicitly to false they will remain.

Comment: so if you just want to add your regEx to the username, you can attach without options to merge (without index or unique as they are already defined)...

Comment: can you make an example, i always get the "index already defined with different option error" even if i drop it first